In a flutter Android & iOS app, how can I send a notification to a user when a specific date for that user has been reached in firestore?
Situation
I have a firestore database containing documents for all my users. Each user has a collection of documents that each have a date.
The objective is to, for each user and every day, check if that date has been reached for the user in question and to send a notification for that user if the date has been reached. The notification would ideally contain information about the document from which the date has been reached.
I think (I haven't really tested it yet) I have already handled the code to receive the notification, so all I need now is to actually send the notification.
I need this to work with both Android and iOS
The problem
All I have found about sending notifications with firebase is about sending notifications as a topic, which would not include the date condition.
I found other ways to send notifications but none of them included sending them when the date was reached.
Using cloud functions isn't an option either, knowing I would have to pay for it.
My last idea was to use a timer in my flutter application that would run a method every day. That method would then go get the specific documents from the database, filter them according to their date, and then send notifications to the phone with the remaining documents.
However, even if I might find a way to make that work when the app is in the background, for example if the user switches to another app without closing mine, I don't think this solution would work if the app is terminated. It would definitely stop working if the phone would be shut down.

If you eliminate solutions like Cloud Functions or other backends, you're not likely to make any progress on a solution.  Push notifications using Firebase always involve backend code.

Why do you need to send the notification on that specific date? Why not send it ahead of time, and then display it locally at the right moment?
